# Random Creation Of Spring Bean

Tags: spring, spring-boot, java-8

Defining bean in a spring-boot application (v 2.3.12) as below:

```
@MyConditionalProperty(key="name", value = "false")
    @Bean
    @Profile({"local", "dev"})
    public FilterRegistrationBean<Filter> myfilterBean(FilterOne filter){
        return registerFilter(filter, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
    }

    @MyConditionalProperty(key="name", value = "true")
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<Filter> myfilterBean(FilterTwo filter){
        return registerFilter(filter, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
    }

    private FilterRegistrationBean<Filter> registerFilter(Filter filter, int order) {
        FilterRegistrationBean<Filter> filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
        filterRegistrationBean.setFilter(filter);
        filterRegistrationBean.setOrder(order);
        filterRegistrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/v1/*");

        return filterRegistrationBean;
    }
```

On `local` active profile, when the value of the "`name`" property is "`false`", `myfilterBean` is created as expected with dependency on `FilterOne`. Although, across server restarts, don't see it being created consistently.

What could be the reason for this inconsistency and random behavior? Can it be related to the same method name `myfilterBean` being used to create the bean with one or the other dependency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Renaming one of the `myfilterBean` method works. Renamed it as `myFilterBeanOne` and appropriate bean is loaded based on the conditional property value.